# Hide a preference screen in Android

Tags: android, preferences

I have a preference XML.

First I'm loading the preferences from an XML resource:

```
 addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

and setting some default values to it. After setting the default values, I need to hide (not to remove) one of my preference screen.

My preference XML is:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
    <Preference
                android:title="Account Settings"
                 android:key="customPref" />
    
    <PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/account_1"
                    android:key="account">
            <EditTextPreference
                android:key="username"
                android:title="@string/settings_username"
                android:singleLine="true" />
            <EditTextPreference
                android:key="password"
                android:title="@string/settings_password"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />
                </PreferenceScreen>


    <PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/account_2"
                android:key="account1">
            <EditTextPreference
                android:key="username1"
                android:title="@string/settings_username"
                android:singleLine="true" />
            <EditTextPreference
                android:key="password1"
                android:title="@string/settings_password"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />
                </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I need to hide the `PreferenceScreen`  having

```
title ="@string/account_2
```

Answer (score 3):

easy as:

```
Preference preference = (Preference) findPreference("pref");
PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("pref_screen");
PreferenceCategory preferenceCategory = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("pref_category");
```

To hide the Preference:

```
PreferenceGroup preferenceParent = getParent(preference);
preferenceParent.removePreference(preference);
```

To hide the PreferenceScreen:

```
PreferenceGroup preferenceScreenParent = getParent(preferenceScreen);
preferenceScreenParent.removePreference(preferenceScreen);
```

To hide the PreferenceCategory:

```
PreferenceGroup preferenceCategoryParent = getParent(preferenceCategory);
preferenceCategoryParent.removePreference(preferenceCategory);
```

And the same manner goes to EditTextPreference, CheckBoxPreference, .....

Answer (score 2):

You can duplicate your XML. Then remove the second part like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Preference
                android:title="Account Settings"
                 android:key="customPref" />

    <PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/account_1"
                    android:key="account">
            <EditTextPreference
                android:key="username"
                android:title="@string/settings_username"
                android:singleLine="true" />
            <EditTextPreference
                android:key="password"
                android:title="@string/settings_password"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true" />
                </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then you check your preference to see if it has already been initialized.

If yes, you load the XML above, otherwise the first one.

Comment: Good idea. I found it the easiest to just choose the right XML file based on an if condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to both the Preference, and its parent (a PreferenceCategory, or PreferenceScreen)

```
myPreferenceScreen.remove(myPreference);
```