# Expandable XML PreferenceScreen ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, expandablelistview

I've looked around all over the place and I still could not find anything that makes this.

I am trying to set a `listView` where I click on the parent, and the children will appear at the bottom, like an Expandable `ListView`.

The problem is I need to do this in the XML folder, which you can't use layout properties. The `buttons` are labeled like
`com.android.widget.preferences.SettingYouWant` `android:title` `android:key` etc etc.

So I don't know how I would make the `listview` open up the children as the widget preferences. The actual layout is described in the layouts.xml folder, and then the preference screen is described in the java file so I can use `<com.android.widget.preferences.PreferenceScreen` and put the onclick in the xml. Here's an example.

```
<com.android.widget.preferences.PreferenceScreen android:title="Title"  com:pref_icon="@drawable/arrow_down"(?) com:preference_screen="@xml/another_screen" />
```

The (?) after the com:pref_icon is because I wanted to try and get it to be an arrow down and then an arrow up when the `listview` is opened.

I want this button to open up a `listview` under it of other `buttons` like it, that are described on the java folder. I don't really know how else to explain this but if anyone needs me to clarify, please ask, as I am just as confused.

Comment: you can remove and add child data on PreferenceScreen click event

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I have the XML set up so all the settings are run through the xml, and the actual process is run through the java. Is there a way to set it up so on preference screen will open up the expandable listview of the other Preference Screens that use <com.android.widget. etc..?

Comment: refer [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282817/hide-a-preference-screen-in-android), you might get idea

Comment: if `com.android.widget.preferences.PreferenceScreen` is a custom preference that you built yourself, then write the hide/unhide logic in that java file also in the xml layout it depends on.

Comment: So instead of it opening up a new screen, it unhides the buttons? What has me confused is that they are PreferenceScreens so they are based off on layout, but with different characteristics like checkbox. list, normal pref, and I can't figure out how to set those to be apart of the list.

Comment: In simple terms: an expandable listview in a preferencescreen. the buttons  are based off a layout file which describes their style. The java file includes this, like one button <com.android.widgets.preferences.links has the base button as res/layout/base_pref_screen but the code itself is doing other stuff to enable the setting. I don't know how to implement these buttons in apref screen to do the expanding listview.